# Deploying static resources with MavensMate

Tags: mavensmate

In Eclipse, when I want to deploy some static resources I've been working on, I do the following:

Right click on the build.xml file -> Run As -> Ant build... -> deploy.static.resources

In my MavensMate, what is the equivalent SVN command to deploy my static resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
mavensmate new-resource-bundle path/to/my/static/resource

mavensmate deploy-resource-bundle path/to/my/resource/bundle
```

Follow [this](http://www.joe-ferraro.com/2012/12/mavensmate-resource-bundles/) tutorial fore more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile (deploy) any available resource by the following way

1. for single resource:

[image]

2. for a few resources which can be selected via Ctrl + click
   [image]